# c programming greatest of 10 numbers .whats wrong with my code? i dont get the output

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{      
    int a[10], greatest = 0, i;     
    a[0] = greatest;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", a[i]);
    } 

    for (i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        if (a[0] < a[i])
        {
            greatest = a[i];
        }    
    }
    printf("%d", a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (a[0] < a[i])
        {
            greatest = a[i];
        }   ` means "if the first element is lesser than the current then the current one is the greatest". Which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The logic is completely wrong. Read it out loud to yourself.

Comment: ..or step through it with your debugger, something you should have done before posting here:(

Answer (score 3):

For starters (apart from other logical errors) this statement

```
a[0] = greatest;
```

does not make sense.

The program can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

int main( void )
         ^^^^^
{      
    int a[N];
    int greatest;
    int i;     

    for ( i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ ) scanf( "%d", &a[i] );
                                             ^^^^^ 
    greatest = a[0];
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    for ( i = 1 ; i < N ; i++ )
    {
        if ( greatest < a[i] ) greatest = a[i];
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }

    printf( "%d\n", greatest );
                  ^^^^^^^^

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Damn! My program is identical to yours (except that I hard-coded 10 instead of #defining it), you've beaten me by literally 20 seconds... I guess I'll just discard my answer then. :-(

Comment: @FabioTurati Let's think that we wrote the answer together.:)

Answer (score 2):

There are many issues with your code. Lets take it one by one

---

1)
`scanf()` needs an address.

```
scanf("%d", &a[i]);
            ^
```

add an ampersand.

---

2)
You do not reset the value of `i` before using it in the last `printf()`.

```
printf("%d", a[i]);
```

Therefore, `i = 10`, which is out of bound fro the array `a[]`, therefore leading to undefined behavior.

---

3)
Since you are storing the values in the variable `greatest` in the `for` loop here,

```
for (i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
{
    if (a[0] < a[i])
    {
        greatest = a[i];
    }    
}
```

while comparing for the greatest number, you should also compare with the variable `greatest`. Because it would contain the the updated greatest value always. And better store the first value in the variable `greatest` before you start with this loop

```
greatest = a[0];
for (i = 1 ; i < 10 ; i++)
{
    if (greatest < a[i])
    {
        greatest = a[i];
    }    
}
```

And later also, print the value in the `greatest` variable.

```
printf("%d", greatest);
```

---

**NOTE:** 
Use the standard definition of `main()`

```
int main(void) //if no command line arguments.
```

Comment: And `printf("%d", a[i]);` is UB.